# Fetch data from third model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rails-activerecord

I have such model structure:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, :through => :user_groups
  has_many :orders
  has_many :user_groups
end
```

-

```
class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

-

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, :through => :user_groups
end
```

In model group i have field *markup*.
How can i for every user via it's user_groups get group's markup field?

I try so:

```
user.user_groups.each do |u|
  summ += u.groups.markup
end
```

Sure it is not working... But how to fetch data from third model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.groups.map(&:markup).sum` should do it just fine

EDIT:

I used #flat_map because I was thinking that it was a nested array. But has_many :through would combine it into a single result list, so #map will be fine

EDIT2:

In discussion with @VladisAzamaris, it was pointed out that the `markup` column is a float, so `sum` is more appropriate than `join`

Comment: flat_map + join does the summation. If you do `sum = user.groups.flat_map(&:markup).join('')`, then sum will hold the combined markup. I'd recommend doing some Ruby tutorials first if this is not very apparent

Comment: no! if i do this, i just see in view array of my values, but not summ

Comment: the join does the same as your previous `+=`

Comment: it is not working... i call it, but in view, for fetched 20 and 4 values i see not 24, but 204, if i delete join i see [20,4] !

Comment: ahhh, sorry, thought they were strings. replace `join('')` with `sum`

Comment: if i replace user.groups.map(&:markup).join('') with user.groups.map(&:markup).sum i get undefined method `sum' for [20.0, 4.0]:Array

Comment: This is now just basic Ruby.... in 1.9+ it is sum, it sounds like you may be on Ruby 1.8, so you'll need to either use #inject (`inject(0) { |a, i| a + i }`) or upgrade. Like I said, it sounds like you would benefit from some pure Ruby tutorials.

Comment: no, man i'm on 1.9.3.... have tried also in rails console... it is not working solution...

Comment: This is becoming an extended chat, which isn't ok, and something is missing here. In current versions of Rails, Array's have a `#sum` method, that can operate on an array of floats. I would see if `[20.0, 4.0].sum` works in the console, then figure out why it doesn't work, or why it does and the model method doesn't.

Comment: sorry... I write summ but not sum (on russian maner)... that was the problem... also sum is good, but not join

Answer (score 1):

First off, may as well take advantage of that `has_many :through` here:

```
user.groups # => all the groups to which this user belongs
```

How about something like this to get the markup? This'll put 'em all in a list, unless you actually did want them all in one big string, in which case you'd join 'em.

```
user.groups.map(&:markup)
```

Also, if there aren't any other fields on the `UserGroup` model, consider a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, in which Rails handles that glue `UserGroup` model for you rather than having you declare it.